# How to compile a pdf in RStudio Markdown?

Tags: r, pdf, markdown

I've just installed RStudio and I want to knit a pdf document and I get this error message red:

> Error: LaTeX failed to compile
> diapositivas-PRYE-bugfac8d2bfe22dfde4bdebadc8cd65b2798b315d7788f1f7bef1c4c579a8d5f325.tex.
> See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. Además:
> Warning messages: 1: In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout())
> f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :   '"pdflatex"' not found 2: In
> system2(...) : '"pdflatex"' not found Ejecución interrumpida
>
> No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF
> output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform:
> https://www.latex-project.org/get/
>
> If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R:
> tinytex::install_tinytex()
>
> Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org
>
> MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/   (NOTE: Download with
> Safari rather than Chrome *strongly* recommended)
>
> Linux: Use system package manager

I've tried installing the "knitr" package, and run this:

```
install.packages("knitr")
library(knitr)
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

but still getting the same error.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Ivan.

Answer (score 8):

So you've tried this.

```
install.packages("knitr")
library(knitr)
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

But try this instead. You need to have the tinytex package to use it's install function.

```
install.packages("knitr")
library(knitr)
install.packages("tinytex")
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Comment: Yes, you are right and it works! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I always run into that same problem. Try knitting it to .html, opening the .html file, and then exporting the .html file to pdf.

Comment: That is a last hour hack I've used before, thank you. You should try this script: `install.packages("knitr"); library(knitr); install.packages("tinytex"); tinytex::install_tinytex()`. It worked for me!